# deploy the app on vercel cloud if the frontend is created using create-react-app and the backend using express server

Tags: reactjs, express, web-deployment, aws-code-deploy, vercel

Can anyone guide me on how to deploy my app whose frontend side has been created using create react app and the backend using express. My folder structure is

```
root
 api
 client
```

The official documentation only shows how to deploy the create-react-app but I couldn't find any docs on how to deploy if the app has both create react app and express. I'm totally new to deployment so please don't mind if the question seems idiotic.

Comment: https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel

Vercel don't really support backend, but you can deploy your express as an serverless app, just follow the guide above

Comment: Vercel is made for serverless functions, not for express servers. You may deploy your whole server as a serverless functions, but you'd ultimately defeat the purpose of Vercel's platform :-)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' what do I do then? I deployed my client-side on vercel. I feel happy to see my website but I feel bad when I can't even fill the contact form. It's useless without the backend. Is there any other free hoisting service where I can deploy just the backend?

Comment: My purpose is to deploy my complete project. I don't care about vercel's purpose :(

Comment: @NishantKumar, there are plenty of options where to deploy express app, like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com). Alternatively, you may use Vercel for backend as well, if you convert your app to use standalone functions (via Next.js' API routes).